# How to control few methods in task scheduler in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I have a console application as shown below which has 4 methods like  `Sendmail(),Downloadfile(),ProcessFile(),ExportFIle()`,i made this as a task scheduler which will run everyday morning  8:AM .But some time like 12 o clock i want to run only `ProcessFile()` and `ExportFIle()`.So what i used to do is, i will open application in Visual studio then will comment the `Sendmail`() and `Downloadfile`() so that i can run only the rest two functions.But the problem is if i forget to uncomment the code ,next day morning 8 am scheduler will run only with two functions .Is there any way i can manage this situation without commenting the code??

```
namespace Testconsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Sendmail();
            Downloadfile();
            ProcessFile();
            ExportFIle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass command line parameter into your program from `TaskScheduler`. Let's say for the one who runs on 12:00 you create a new `TaskScheduler` which launches your program with `--download_only` parameter. after you need to read it inside your program and treat appropriately.

Comment: If you **don't want 3rd party dlls** please update your question to say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a configuration XML file. The console application must then read the file to decide which methods to run, and then you can alter the XML whenever you need a change without having to alter the code itself.

You can also split your application up into 4 different console applications, and then run each individually. In their own scheduled tasks. By using Windows task scheduler.

Alternatively, you can alter the main method to accept parameters that will indicate which methods to run, and then include them in the scheduled task, you are already running.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Sendmail();
            Downloadfile();
            ProcessFile();
            ExportFile();
        }

        foreach (string s in args)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case "SendMail":
                    Sendmail();
                    break;
                //etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But all functions are related and in morning for the first time these all should happen sequentially, then after that we can run at any order

Comment: So lets say you accept a parameter string, and not parameters. 
no parameters = run all.

parameter string "SendMail" executes "send mail" I edited my answer to include an example @Peter

Comment: i will check this,?one case is sufficient??

Comment: from when the switch clause works with strings ? as far as i know works only with int or enums...

Comment: @Clock Well, I am certainly able to. This is a C# question.

Comment: @peter No. you need to implement a case for each method you want to execute. So if you include both "SendMail" and "Processfile" it will do so, in the order you specify the arguements.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to utilize a scheduling framework like [CronNet](https://github.com/kevincolyar/CronNET)

**UPDATE** If you don't want a third party dll to manage this - you could introduce some command line arguments to your console app:

- By default, if no arguments are passed - all tasks are run
- If a specific task name is specified - run only that task
- Introduce some simple mapping from string command line args to your methods - either simple `Dictionary<string,Action>` or just some reflection - convention based mapping

For example:
`myScheduler.exe ProcessFile ExportFile`

You can schedule each of your tasks as separate `CronJob`

Your code could look something like this *(this is based on CronNet wiki)*

```
using System.Threading;
using CronNET;

namespace CronNETExample.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly CronDaemon cron_daemon = new CronDaemon();            

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cron_daemon.add_job(new CronJob("* * * * *", Sendmail));
            cron_daemon.add_job(new CronJob("* * * * *", Downloadfile));
            cron_daemon.add_job(new CronJob("* * * * *", ProcessFile));
            cron_daemon.add_job(new CronJob("* * * * *", ExportFIle));

            cron_daemon.start();

            // Wait and sleep forever. Let the cron daemon run.
            while(true) Thread.Sleep(6000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want third party DLL

Answer (score 1):

You could compile both versions of the code and forget about VS.

Anyway a more elegant way of doing this without all the commenting and compiling would be using a chron scheduler like Quartz.Net and use your program as a windows service.

Comment: I don't want third party DLL

Comment: Then take the first part of the answer, two compiled versions of the program

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is wrapping your "actuator" functions into two separate schedule functions:

```
namespace Testconsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          if (args[0] = "8")
            ScheduleFor8();
          if (args[0] = "12")
            ScheduleFor12();

        }
        static void ScheduleFor8() {
            Sendmail();
            Downloadfile();
            ProcessFile();
            ExportFIle();
        }
        static void ScheduleFor12() {
            ProcessFile();
            ExportFIle();
        }
    }
}
```